# Grails Spring Security LDAP intermittent authentication failure

Tags: grails, spring-security-ldap

We have an application which has been deployed under Tomcat 7 for over a year and was working until a recent upgrade of the open LDAP server.  Since the upgrade, we have intermittent login failures.  There will be strings of success, alternating with failures.  The LDAP server admin placed a packet sniffer between the application server and the LDAP server, and determined that there are two different packet signatures.  His opinion is that the application must be sending these two different logins, but the code has not changed, nor has the application server changed.

We are using:

- Grails 2.2.2
- springSecurityCore 1.2.7.3
- springSecurityLdap 1.0.6

Here is what he reports:

```
Successful:
[09/Apr/2015:14:21:18 -0400] conn=17363 fd=64 slot=64 connection from 172.18.4.34 to 172.18.4.24
[09/Apr/2015:14:21:18 -0400] conn=17363 op=0 BIND dn="cn=hamerm,cn=Users,dc=lcc,dc=edu" method=128 version=3
[09/Apr/2015:14:21:18 -0400] conn=17363 op=0 RESULT err=0 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0 dn="cn=hamerm,cn=users,dc=lcc,dc=edu"
[09/Apr/2015:14:21:18 -0400] conn=17363 op=1 SRCH base="cn=hamerm,cn=Users,dc=lcc,dc=edu" scope=0 filter="(objectClass=*)" attrs="mail cn sn givenName"
[09/Apr/2015:14:21:18 -0400] conn=17363 op=1 RESULT err=0 tag=101 nentries=0 etime=0
[09/Apr/2015:14:21:18 -0400] conn=17363 op=2 UNBIND

Unsuccessful:
[09/Apr/2015:14:19:17 -0400] conn=13546 fd=71 slot=71 connection from 172.18.4.34 to 172.18.4.23
[09/Apr/2015:14:19:17 -0400] conn=13546 op=0 BIND dn="" method=128 version=3
[09/Apr/2015:14:19:17 -0400] conn=13546 op=0 RESULT err=0 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0 dn=""
[09/Apr/2015:14:19:17 -0400] conn=13546 op=1 SRCH base="cn=users,dc=lcc,dc=edu" scope=2 filter="(&(objectClass=*)(uid=hamerm))" attrs=ALL
[09/Apr/2015:14:19:17 -0400] conn=13546 op=1 RESULT err=0 tag=101 nentries=1 etime=0 notes=U
[09/Apr/2015:14:19:17 -0400] conn=13546 op=2 BIND dn="cn=hamerm,cn=Users,dc=lcc,dc=edu" method=128 version=3
[09/Apr/2015:14:19:17 -0400] conn=13546 op=2 RESULT err=0 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0 dn="cn=hamerm,cn=users,dc=lcc,dc=edu"
[09/Apr/2015:14:20:22 -0400] conn=13546 op=-1 fd=71 closed - B1
```

Note that this is coming from the same application, and the same server, using the same URL to log in.

We are all at a loss to locate where the two different sorts of packets are arising.  I need to make it send just the successful sort of LDAP query.

Here is the relevant part of Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider','anonymousAuthenticationProvider','rememberMeAuthenticationProvider']
// we will be using anonymous bind
//grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'uid=admin,ou=system'
//grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = ''
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = ''
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://myserver.lcc.edu:389'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase = 'ou=Groups,dc=lcc,dc=edu'
// at this time, we do not need group information
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchFilter = 'member={0}'
// necessary for Active Directory
//grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true
//grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter="sAMAccountName={0}" //for active directory you need this
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true 
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions= false// our DN string: cn=%LDAP_USER%,cn=Users,dc=lcc,dc=edu
//grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'dc=example,dc=com'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'cn=Users,dc=lcc,dc=edu'
//grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.attributesToReturn = ['mail', 'cn', 'sn', 'givenName']
//grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authenticator.attributesToReturn = ['mail', 'cn', 'sn', 'givenName']
```

The LDAP admin further says that if we can get the request sent to be the same as what is coming from our ApEx applications, all would be well.  That packet pattern looks like:

```
[10/Apr/2015:11:07:54 -0400] conn=67850 fd=69 slot=69 connection from 172.18.4.34 to 172.18.4.24
[10/Apr/2015:11:07:54 -0400] conn=67850 op=0 BIND dn="cn=LEESA,cn=Users,dc=lcc,dc=edu" method=128 version=3
[10/Apr/2015:11:07:54 -0400] conn=67850 op=0 RESULT err=0 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0 dn="cn=leesa,cn=users,dc=lcc,dc=edu"
[10/Apr/2015:11:07:54 -0400] conn=67850 op=1 UNBIND
[10/Apr/2015:11:07:54 -0400] conn=67850 op=1 fd=69 closed - U1
```

What should be done to Config.groovy and/other other config files to produce the good pattern?  Or, if there appears to be nothing wrong with the config, what could be causing this?